# Handling two different connection closing in a try catch

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

If you're opening connections usually what you do is a try-catch-finally

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle the exception
} finally {
    close();
}
```

In my scenario I've two catch and two different closing: close() in the normal case and closeStrange() if a StrangeException is thrown.

I came up with something like this:

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch(StrangeException e) {
    closeStrange();
    throw new MyExc(e);
} catch(Exception e) {
    close();
    throw new MyExc(e);
}
close();
```

I would like to know if handle this situation in this way it's safe.

**EDIT:**

Probably it wasn't clear: I want just one of the closing to be called.
closeStrange() if the StrangeException is thrown,
close() if another Exception or none is thrown.

Comment: what exactly is done in the closeStrange() and the close() method? Please provide an example.

Comment: you will be calling close() twice in the case of normal exception this way.

Comment: the last `close()` is always invoked. even after the first one and `closeStrange()` - when exactly are you trying to call `close()`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the throwing of the custom exception.. : /

Comment: Your code will still fail to call `close` in case of an `Error`. Going with `finally` is really the safest option.

Comment: Yes, that's was my doubt. But why it will fail?

Comment: When you get an `Error` you'll find out why :) Do you think your code is and always will be so bulletproof that it will never throw an `Error`? Such a guarantee is not in your hands, anyway.

Comment: What you mean with `Error`? Are you referring to one of the two exceptions or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the way you're handling this at the moment isn't safe:

- You're not using a `finally` block, so any non-Exception that's thrown will leave you without closing the connection
- You're "handling" any exception, which is almost certainly not appropriate

You probably want:

```
boolean closedStrangely = false;
try {
   ...
} catch (StrangeException e) {
    closeStrangely();
    closedStrangely = true;
    throw e; // Or maybe not, or maybe throwing some custom exception
} finally {
    if (!closedStrangely) {
        close();
    }
}
```

Note that if `closeStrangely()` throws an exception, this will attempt to close it "normally". If you don't want that behaviour, set `closedStrangely` to true *before* calling `closeStrangely`.

EDIT: Even if you want to throw a custom exception in some cases, you almost certainly *shouldn't* be catching `Exception`.

Comment: If `MyExc` is unchecked, this is exactly what he **should** be doing, except that he should precede it with `catch (RuntimeException)` to pass through exceptions that already are unchecked.

Comment: I've edited the question. I forgot to throw the custom exceptions. Do you think that the flag would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to ensure that the resource is closed exactly once, this is the cleanest solution, and the only one offered with this property.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear about this, I want just one of the closing (close() OR closeStrangely())

Comment: @Enrichman: So follow the suggestion I included in the answer - set `closedStrangely` to true before you try doing it.

Comment: I've a doubt: shouldn't also the other closing be inside the finally? Like an if-else instead of just an if?

Answer (score 1):

A more common pattern might be.

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch(StrangeException e) {
    // handle strange exception without closing.
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle the exception without closing.
} finally {
    close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch(Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof StrangeException) {
        closeStrange();
    } else {
        close();
    }
} finally {
   close();
}
```

You can check the exception using instanceof

Comment: In case of exception you will call `close()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
try {
    doSomething();
    close();
} catch(StrangeException e) {
    closeStrange();
    throw;
} catch(Throwable e) {
    close();
    throw;
}
```

In this way you call one and only one of `close` or `closeStrange` in any case and you let exceptions "pass through".

Comment: This assumes that you should call only `closeStrange` and not `close` in case a `StrangeException` is thrown. If this isn't the case, use the solution proposed by @dystroy.

Comment: This still has the potential of calling `close` twice, although usually this wouldn't be a show stopper. A slightly more worrying aspect is that it may call `close` and then `closeStrange`.